# C++ execute multiple commands with timer in shell

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell

what is the best way to execute multiple shell commands with a delay between one and another in the same shell?

E.g., this is a sample code that executes `cd` and `ls` commands but in different shells. How can I add a 10 seconds delay and running them in the same shell? Maybe with `usleep`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cerrno>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main() {
   system("gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'cd; ls; exec bash'");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system()` is horrible for multiple reasons (like security exploits, lack of control over the running program and more), forget it exists and *never* use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

You should use `fork` + `exec*` (+ `wait`) instead of `system`: `system` is vulnerable to alias and you can't handle well error with it.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

//Function made in less than 5 minute
// You should improve it (error handling, ...)
// I use variadic template to be able to give a non fixed
// number of parameters
template<typename... str>
void my_system(str... p) {
    // Fork create a new process
    switch fork() {
        case 0: // we are in the new process
            execl(p..., (char*)nullptr); // execl execute the executable passed in parameter
            break;
        case -1: // Fork returned an error
            exit(1);
        default: // We are in the parent process
            wait(); // We wait for the child process to end
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    // start a command
    my_system(<executable path>, "cd") ;
    // sleep for 2 second
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    // ....
    my_system(<executable path>, "ls") ;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    my_system(<executable path>, "exec", "bash") ;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
}
```

**WARNING** this code was not tested, do not do any error handling and may have bugs ! I will let you fix it. Check the man page for the call to the posix library (`execl`, `fork`, `wait`) and the above link for `sleep_for` and `chrono`.

Comment: can you show me how to write what you said by using my part of code?
thanks :)

Comment: I've added an example. Do not simply copy/paste my example as it is not tested (which mean it may have bug) and as no error handling.